# Seeing if projected lines intersect a circle

Tags: geometry

**The Problem:**

Let $\theta$ be the angle of a line that intersects $(0,0) $, and let ($x_0,y_0)$ be the center point of a circle, where the circle is tangent to $(0,0)$. Say we 'shoot off' various perpendicular lines from the main line at all points along the x axis: (For my examples I will be using a  midpoint of ($10,2.5)$ and a line angle of 45 degrees)

[image: Angles and scale not at all accurate. Blame MS Paint, not me]
For what values of of X (the x position at their origin along the main line) do these perpendicular lines intersect the circle?

**What I have tried:**

Seeing as I have never completed one Geometry class in my life, this isn't exactly my area of expertise. But I  tried my best.
So, the equation for each of these perpendicular lines is:
$$y=\tan\left({\frac{\pi}{180}[360-\theta]}\right)x+c$$
The $360-\theta$ makes it perpendicular and then the $\frac{\pi}{180}$ converts it to radians. The $c$ is simply how far along the x axis it intersects. Already we have run into a problem - we won't be able to get data on what values of x when x is the origin of each perpendicular line on the main line, but x where x is the x intercept of each perpendicular line. But let's disregard that for a second, and I'll show you the rest of my work to possibly springboard off of.

So, we have to see which line intersect the circle. To do this, we can use the formula for distance from a line to a point:

$$\operatorname{distance}(ax+by+c=0, (x_0, y_0)) = \frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}. $$
Using the centerpoint of the circle as the point and our perpendicular line equation as our line, since y will always have a coefficient of -1 and we need to check whether it is within $r$ (where $r$ is the radius of the circle*) of the centerpoint, we can simplify to:
$$\frac{|ax_0-y_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \leq r$$
Where $a$ is the coefficient of x in the perpendicular line equation, $\tan\left({\frac{\pi}{180}[360-\theta]}\right)$ and $c$ is what we add in the end that dictates how far the x intercept is.

Alas, from here, I do not know how to solve that equation for the bounds of c, plus we have our first problem, that it will give us data based on the x intercept of each line and not it's origin on the main line. Am I on the right track, or is these a much simpler way of doing this? If you want to give number examples in your answer, please use the constants I used in my image. Thank you for your help!  If you have any questions or need clarification, just ask!

<sup>*Which will be the same as $y_0$ because the circle touches 0,0, but just for notation's sake we call it $r$.</sup>

Comment: It looks like the circle is actually tangent to the $x$-axis instead of passing through the origin as you’ve written at top. Is that the case? At any rate, you simply need to find the orthogonal projection of the circle’s center onto the line and then go a distance of $r=|y_0|$ in either direction from that point along the line. In effect, you find the circle’s shadow on the line.

Comment: @amd Sorry about that, I meant the circle touched 0,0, not the center point. I've updated the question. And I'm terribly sorry, but I'm in 7th grade and haven't really studied geometry in depth. Could you possibly explain what an orthogonal projection from a point onto a line is and how I find it? Googling has turned up almost nothing.

Comment: BTW, $360°-\theta$ doesn’t give you the perpendicular—consider $\theta=0$. You want $\theta+90°$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking about casting perpendicular lines out from the given line, imagine this equivalent problem: given a line that passes through the origin, a circle (for now, let’s assume they don’t intersect), and a light source sufficiently large and far away that the light rays are parallel to each other and perpendicular to the given line, what is the shadow cast by the circle onto the line? This is basically what is meant by “orthogonal projection.”

You should be able to convince yourself that, because the light rays are parallel and hitting the line at right angles, the length of the circle’s shadow will be equal to its diameter. So, we really only need to find the “shadow” of the circle’s center and then go out a distance equal to the circle’s radius in both directions from there.

Finding the center’s projection onto the line is a matter of solving a system of two linear equations. The line’s equation is, as you no doubt already know, $y=mx$, where $m=\tan\theta$. The light rays are perpendicular to our line, which means that their slope is $\tan(\theta+\frac\pi2)=-\frac1m$, so an equation for the light ray that passes through the circle’s center is $(y-y_0)=-\frac1m(x-x_0)$. I’ll leave finding the solution to this pair of equations to you. Once you have this point, you can find the edges of the shadow via trigonometry: the endpoints will be $(x-\cos\theta,y-\sin\theta)$ and $(x+\cos\theta,y+\sin\theta)$. This doesn’t quite work if the angle of the line is a multiple of 90 degrees since in that case either $m$ or its reciprocal is undefined, but the light rays are then parallel to one of the coordinate axes, so determining the projection is really simple.

If the circle and line intersect, you have to imagine a light source on either side of the line, but the math is exactly the same.

If you’re familiar with vectors, this calculation doesn’t even require solving a system of equations if you use them instead. If $\vec v$ is some vector in the direction of the line, then the orthogonal projection of an arbitrary vector $\vec w$ onto the line is given by ${\vec w\cdot\vec v\over\vec v\cdot\vec v}\vec v$. From there, the circle’s projection extends by $\pm r{\vec v\over\|v\|}$.